# printk is line buffered?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, printk

On Linux application level all printf messages go to `stdout` and all err messages goto `stderr`. Where

stderr is usually unbuffered and

stdout is line-buffered

So at `kernel space` when we use `printk()`  with or without `KERN_ERR` and such other level specifying macro then how this messages are buffered?

Does `dmesg` has any separate mechanism?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All that `printk()` does is to simply add few more bytes into in-memory ring-buffer (and wrap around if end of buffer reached). So, it does not make sense to say whether it is line-buffered or not - this just does not apply.

Also, while in user space `stdout`, `stderr` make sense, this is not the case in kernel and for `printk()`: it does not write to `stdout` because there is no such thing in kernel.

Granted, something takes care of actually delivering contents of this ring-buffer to the user - whether it is printing it on serial console or retrieving it with `dmesg`, and this typically looks for LF characters to separate lines.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you can answer my below queries :
1. At the time of panic, few of my pr_info prints are not flushed to serial console. What can I do to get them(considering making them emerg is not an option)?
2. Is there a way I can flush the kernel buffer?

Thanks a lot.